# sorting and comparing columns in Big Query SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a requirement to to sort and compare columns values. In a table having 6 columns
[image]
Need to do sorting for A_Length, A_breadth, A_Width and similar sorting need to be done for B_length, B_breadth and B_width

After sorting comparison need to do be done between A_* and B_* column based on their sorting order like
After sorting:
[image]

comparison need to be done with out put true or False
(3<11=True and  22<22= false and 23<32 =true) over all result for this is false

(5<11=true and  11<22=true and 17<32=true ) over all result for this is true

(17<11=false and 23<22=false and 27<32=true) over all result for this is False

In Biq query i can do greatest and least but not sure how to take the 3rd value(that is neither greatest nor least)

Let me know if any one can suggest a logic  Its a big table having multiple column and above 6 column will be part of it.

Some more info below :
Sorting is smallest to largest. suppose i have 6 columns with values: A_Len=3, A_Bred=15,A_Wid=10, B_Len=20, B_Bred=11,B_Wid=7 . So in this first sorting for A_* columns is needed (3,10,15) then sorting for B_* column needed(7,11,20). Then in same order comparison(less than) need to be done between A_* and B_* sorted values (3<7 = result True , 10<11 = result true ,15<20= result true), i need the output after comparison as true or false  . Need an suggestion how this can be done in GCP BQ , all these 6 column are part of a table.

Regards,

Comment: absolutely not clear: 1) logic of sorting - please provide explanation on how exactly sorting is happening 2) and what is the expected result? - please provide example of output - based on presented input data

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant, Sorting is smallest to largest. suppose i have 6 columns with values:

Comment: i was not asking for is it ASC or DESC - read again my comments and provide more details!! just update your questions with as much details as to allow us to help you

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant, Sorting is smallest to largest. suppose i have 6 columns with values: A_Len=3, A_Bred=15,A_Wid=10, B_Len=20, B_Bred=11,B_Wid=7 . So in this first sorting for A_* columns is needed (3,10,15) then sorting for B_* column needed(7,11,20). Then in same order comparison(less than) need to be done between A_* and B_* sorted values (3<7 = result True , 10<11 = result true ,15<20= result true), i need the output after comparison as true or false  . Need an suggestion how this can be done in GCP BQ , all these 6 column are part of a table.

Comment: ok. so sorting is clear! can you show expected final result based on sample data you have in your question?

Comment: hi @MikhailBerlyant, The output i need is whether true or False for 3 values :(3<7=true and  10<11=true and 15<20=true ) over all result for this is true. Similarly need to for all the rows in table. I have one idea of using greatest and least to do the 2 values comparison but not sure how to check for 3 rd value(that is neither greatest nor least)

Comment: words are still not making it clear! just show example of expected output same way as you did for input data

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want do a comparison with something that is not quite the table you currently have. It seems that you want to sort each column individually, without affecting the others, and then compare.

You could try something like this (changing all the instances of `TABLE` for your table name):

```
SELECT 
  sorted_A_LENGTH.A_LENGTH,
  sorted_A_BREADTH.A_BREADTH,
  sorted_A_WIDTH.A_WIDTH,
  sorted_B_LENGTH.B_LENGTH,
  sorted_B_BREADTH.B_BREADTH,
  sorted_B_WIDTH.B_WIDTH,
  sorted_A_LENGTH.A_LENGTH < Sorted_B_LENGTH.B_LENGTH,
  sorted_A_BREADTH.A_BREADTH < sorted_B_BREADTH.B_BREADTH,
  sorted_A_WIDTH.A_WIDTH < Sorted_B_WIDTH.B_WIDTH

FROM 
  (SELECT A_LENGTH, row_number() OVER (ORDER  A_LENGTH) AS row_num FROM TABLE ORDER BY ASC) as sorted_A_LENGTH

LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT A_BREADTH, row_number() OVER (ORDER  A_BREADTH) AS row_num FROM TABLE ORDER BY ASC) as sorted_A_BREADTH
  ON sorted_A_LENGTH.row_num = sorted_A_BREADTH.row_num

LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT A_WIDTH, row_number() OVER (ORDER  A_WIDTH) AS row_num FROM TABLE ORDER BY ASC) as sorted_A_WIDTH
ON sorted_A_LENGTH.row_num = sorted_A_WIDTH.row_num

LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT B_LENGTH, row_number() OVER (ORDER  B_LENGTH) AS row_num FROM TABLE ORDER BY ASC) as sorted_B_LENGTH
ON sorted_A_LENGTH.row_num = sorted_B_LENGTH.row_num

LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT B_BREADTH, row_number() OVER (ORDER  B_BREADTH) AS row_num FROM TABLE ORDER BY ASC) as sorted_B_BREADTH
ON sorted_A_LENGTH.row_num = sorted_B_BREADTH.row_num

LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT B_WIDTH, row_number() OVER (ORDER  B_WIDTH) AS row_num FROM TABLE ORDER BY ASC) as sorted_B_WIDTH
ON sorted_A_LENGTH.row_num = sorted_B_WIDTH.row_num
```

Comment: Forgot to say, if you want the comparisons as boolean  you can use cast, for example: `CAST(sorted_A_LENGTH.A_LENGTH < Sorted_B_LENGTH.B_LENGTH AS BOOL)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select *, 
  a_length < b_length as length_a_less_b,
  a_breadth < b_breadth as breadth_a_less_b,
  a_width < b_width as width_a_less_b
from (
  select * from(select * from your_table limit 0) union all
  select a_arr[offset(0)], a_arr[offset(1)], a_arr[offset(2)],
    b_arr[offset(0)], b_arr[offset(1)], b_arr[offset(2)]
  from your_table, 
  unnest([struct((
    select array_agg(a order by a) from unnest([a_length, a_breadth, a_width]) a
  ) as a_arr)]),
  unnest([struct((
    select array_agg(b order by b) from unnest([b_length, b_breadth, b_width]) b
  ) as b_arr)])
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question

[image]

output is

[image]